# Each composite (positive) $n$ has a (positive) prime divisor no greater than $\sqrt{n}$.

Tags: proof-writing

> $\forall n \in \mathbb N^+$, $n$ is composite $\;\rightarrow\; \exists p\in \mathbb N^+, p \textrm{ is prime  and } p \leq \sqrt{n} \textrm{ and }  p\; |\; n$.

So far this is what I have...
Suppose this is false.

$p> \sqrt{n}$,  $p|n$

Then, $p^2 > n, p|n,$ where $p|n$ is also $pa=n$

Then $p^2 > pa$

Comment: Hint: If $p|n$ so does $n/p$.

Comment: if $p|n$ is for example: 5*6=30, how does $n|p$ become 30*?=5

Comment: If $p = 5$ and $n=30$ and $p|n$ then $\frac np = \frac {30}5 = 6$ and $6|30$.  Which isn't relevant as $5 < \sqrt{30}$.  A better example is $7|35$.  $7 > \sqrt{35}$.  But if $7|35$ then $\frac {35}7 = 5$ also divides $35$ and $5 < \sqrt {35}$.  Another example is $7|28$ so $\frac {28}7 = 4$ has $4|28$ and $4< \sqrt {28}$.  But $4$ isn't prime.  But so what? It must have a prime factor that is even smaller.  i.e.  $2$

Comment: That a dash, not a vertical line  $\frac np$ not "$n|p$.  So  **5**.6 = 30, becomes 5. **6** = 30 trivially.  5 and 6 can't both be larger than that the $\sqrt {30}$.  If $5 > \sqrt{30}$ and $6 > \sqrt{30}$ we get $30=5*6 > \sqrt{30}\sqrt{30} = 30$.  So at least *one* factor is $\le \sqrt{30}$.

Comment: thank you for responding, but could you explain what you're trying to show when there are two factors of a number, where one is greater and the other is less than sqrt of the number? What does that represent? For some reason, I don't see anything wrong with sqrt30 x sqrt30 = 30

Comment: @fleablood Can you answer my question above when you have time? Thanks!

Comment: The question is "show that there is always a prime factor less than or equal to the square root of $n$".  I have shown that factors come in pairs where one is always less than or equal to the square root of $n$ and the other is larger or equal to the square root of $n$.... So that's it!  We are done!  I have shown there is always a factor that is less than or equal to the square root of $n$.  That is what we were asked to prove.  ...Okay, we haven't proven it is prime.  But if it isn't prime it will have a *smaller* prime factor.  So there is a prime factor less or equal to $\sqrt{n}$.

Comment: Who said there was anything wrong with $\sqrt{30} * \sqrt{30} = 30$.  $\sqrt{30} \le \sqrt{30}$ so that is fine.  (except $\sqrt{30}$ isn't an integer.)  Suppose we have $j*k = n$ and $j \le k$..  Then $j \le \sqrt{n} \le k$.  Then if $p$ is prime and $p|j$ then $p \le \sqrt{n}$ and $p|n$ and ..... that's it.... that is *EXACTLY* what we were asked to prove.

Comment: Take a number.... $76$ .... take a factor ...okay .... $19$... Take the "compliment" or $\frac {76}{19} = 4$.  One of them is $\le$ to $\sqrt{76}$. ... Okay... $4 \le 76$.  ... is $4$ prime....  No it is not.  ... okay, take a prime factor of $4$.  $2$.  So 1) $2$ is prime and 2) $2 \le \sqrt {76}$ and 3) $2|76$ and.... what more do you want.  That satisfies *EVERYTHING* you were asked to prove.  Do it with every number.  It will *always* work.

Comment: Try a flow chart. $n$ is composite. A) Take a non trivial factor $k$.  Is $k\le \sqrt{n}$ if so let $m =k$ and go to step C.  If not continue to step B.  B) Let $m = \frac nk$.  $m|n$ and as $k > \sqrt n$ we know $m =\frac nk < \frac n{\sqrt{n}} = \sqrt{n}$. C) we have $m|n$ and $m \le \sqrt{k}$.  Is $m$ prime?  If so let $p=m$ and go to step E.  Otherwise go to step D. D) $m$ is not prime and $m\ne 1$, so $m$ has a prime factor $p$.  $p < m\le \sqrt{n}$ and $p|m$ and $m|n$ so $p|n$.  Go to step E.  E) We are done. $p$ is prime, $p \le \sqrt{n}$ and $p|n$.

Comment: I'm sorry if I have frustrated you. Math is not my strongest subject. But, your explanations really helped with my understanding for this question. I sincerely appreciate your help. Thank you @fleablood

Comment: If your question has been answered, you shouldn't edit out your question. Otherwise anyone who has the same question, won't be able to find the answer that is posted here. So I rolled back your edit for this reason.

Comment: @fleablood One more question... how can you know that when two factors are produced, one is larger than sqrt n and the other is less than sqrt n?

Comment: larger than OR EQUAL and the othe is less than OR EQUAL.  Suppose $m|n$.  Then one of three things will happen.  $m < \sqrt{n}$.   In that case $k = \frac nm > \frac n{\sqrt{n} }= \sqrt{n}$.  Or $m = \sqrt{n}$.  Then $k = \frac nm = \frac n{\sqrt n} = \sqrt{n}$.  Or $m > \sqrt{n}$.  Then $k = \frac nm < \frac n{\sqrt{n}} = \sqrt{n}$.  So if $m*k = n$ then either $m \le \sqrt{n} \le k \le n$. or $k \le \sqrt{n} \le m \le n$.

Comment: Also.  If $m*k = n$ and if $m > \sqrt{n}$ and $n> \sqrt{n}$ then $n = m*k > \sqrt{n}*\sqrt{n} = n$ and that is impossible.  So either $m \le \sqrt{n}$ or $k \le \sqrt{n}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Factors come in pairs.  If $j|n$ then there is a $k$ so that $j*k = n$.  And $k$.... is also a factor.

If one of the factors is $j \ge \sqrt{n}$ then $k = \frac nj \le \frac n{\sqrt{n}} = \sqrt{n}$.

So at least one of $j$ or $k$ is $\le \sqrt{n}$ (and the other is $\ge \sqrt{n}$).

So if we assume $j*k = n$ and $1 \ne k \le j \ne n$ we have $k \le \sqrt{n}$.

If $p$ is any prime factor of $k$ than $p \le \sqrt{n}$ and $p|n$.

That's it.  We're done.